# how to find ALL $\sigma$-algebras of a given sample space?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales

I have a sample space $\Omega$={$\omega_{1}$,$\omega_{2}$,$\omega_{3}$,$\omega_{4}$} and I need to find ALL $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$. I know how to construct some $\sigma$-algebra like $\mathscr{A}$={$\phi$,$\Omega$,$\omega_{1}$,{$\omega_{2}$,$\omega_{3}$,$\omega_{4}$}} but I have no idea about how to find all of them.

Comment: With only four elements, the best way is probably to brute force it and use symmetry.

Comment: you have to create all permuations of the given sample set with the compliment present.. so you have the set with one and total sample space $\Omega$ already, so you need to find the combinations of $A =\lbrace{\omega_1,\omega_2\rbrace}$ and $A^{c}$ etc..

Comment: @D-Poole does all the algebras have the form of {$\phi$,$\Omega$,A,$A^c$}? Is there any of them is something like {$\phi$,$\Omega$,A,$A^c$,B,$B^c$}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the collection of all partitions of $\Omega$ and form the $\sigma$-algebra for each. The number of such partitions is called $B_n$, the Bell number (from Wiki, the source of all truth). $B_4 = 15$.

To see that a $\sigma$-algebra ${\cal A}$ corresponds to a partition, choose $\omega \in \Omega$ and let $A_\omega$ be the intersection of all elements $\cal A$ containing $\omega$. Define the relation $\sim$ by $\omega_1 \sim \omega_2$ **iff** $A_{\omega_1} = A_{\omega_2}$. This is an equivalence relation, hence defines a partition. Then $\cal A$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the partition.

Comment: So if I have a partition of (omit all the $\omega$) {1},{2},{3,4}, I would get a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr{A}$ ={$\phi$,$\Omega$,{1},{2},{3,4},{1,2},{1,3,4},{2,3,4}}?

Comment: Yes. (Essentially arbitrary unions of the partition elements. Everything is finite here, which simplifies life.)